# Color in pointcloud

Tags: kinect, pcl, pcl-1.7, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all, at first ;) my Ubuntu is 12.04 and my gazebo version is 1.9.1 and also my Ros is hydro. I have a simulated kinect in gazebo and i need the color of points, I’ve write below code that i get the data of simulated kinect and converted to pointcloud, also i tried two method that second one is in comment but when i print the color, it's empty but all other thing is ok, any one can help me?

```
void readkinectCallback(const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2& msg)
{
 pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB> pc;

// Convert To Poinct Cloud
pcl::fromROSMsg(msg,pc);

uint32_t rgb = *reinterpret_cast<int*>(&pc.points[100].rgb);
uint8_t r = (rgb >> 16) & 0x0000ff;
uint8_t g = (rgb >> 8) & 0x0000ff;
uint8_t b = (rgb) & 0x0000ff;
   // std::cout<<pc.point[0].r<<pc.point[0].g<<pc.point[0].b<<endl;

}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/93606/color-in-pointcloud/) by [VahidD](https://answers.ros.org/users/4674/vahidd/) on ROS Answers with karma: 72 on 2013-10-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

my problem is solved, my libraries wasn't match with version of my Ros.

---

Originally posted by [VahidD](https://answers.ros.org/users/4674/vahidd/) with karma: 72 on 2013-10-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1